# MySQL "ambiguous field list" and daily average calc

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    City CHAR(10),
    Sales INT NOT NULL,
    Sale_date DATE NOT NULL,
    First_order INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
("Paris",2000,'2018-01-02',1),
("Munich",2000,'2018-02-17',1),
("Paris",2000,'2018-03-31',2),
("Paris",1000,'2017-01-01',2),
("Paris",1000,'2017-02-02',1),
("Paris",1000,'2017-03-02',1),
("Paris",10000,'2018-01-02',2),
("Munich",1000,'2017-01-01',1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f0cb/2

New to SQL, I'm getting an error from this query "Column 'City' in field list is ambiguous" is it a problem with the alias / inner join?

Objectives:

1. Daily Average sales per city (on q1 2018)
2. YoY sales growth Q1_2017 vs Q1_2018
3. Daily Average number of new customers (New customers have a value of 1 in the column "First_order" and 2 for returning customers)

On that 3rd point particularly I am lost, what should I use to calculate this? Count function?

Comment: Add table1 prefix before City field

Comment: You haven't defined your PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one table in a query, qualify all column references.  That is, show the table where they come from.

So:

```
SELECT t1.City, AVG(t1.Sales) as q1_daily_avg_Sales, 
       (SUM(t1.Sales) - tt1.q1_2017_Sales) / tt1.q1_2017_Sales AS Sales_vs_SPLY
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT t1.City, SUM(t1.Sales) AS q1_2017_Sales
      FROM table1 t1
      WHERE t1.Sale_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
      GROUP BY t1.City
     ) tt1
     ON t1.City = tt1.City
WHERE t1.Sale_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY t1.City;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f0cb/11) is the SQL Fiddle.